# Lua scripting language: modify a response body in API gateway

Tags: lua, httpresponse, krakend

I would like to modify the response body returned by the backend.

As background I'll detail my specific problem (but I don't require a solution to the specific problem, just the method for manipulating a response body). I want to insert/add a key value pair to the response body based on the status code of the response and I want to transform snake_case keys into camelCase keys.

For example, given a response with

```
status code: 401
body: {'detail_message': 'user is not logged in'}
```

I want to transform it to a response with

```
status code: 401
body: {'success': False, 'detailMessage': 'user is not logged in'}
```

The rule for success would be True for anything below 400 and False for anything above or equal.

Lua scripting can be used in my API gateway which is Krakend
https://www.krakend.io/docs/endpoints/lua/

The documentation only includes examples for printing the response body and modifying headers but not for modifying the response body.

I have no experience with Lua and only need it for one task. I haven't been able to find online example of response body manipulation which I could play with.

What methods do I need in order to add a key value pair to a response body and to manipulate the keys in the response body?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with KrakenD, but: Have you looked at the Response's `data` field/method? Since the documentation seems to be a bit sparse, you can start by finding out what each of the 'fields' is (`print(type(r.data))`, which should give you either `function` or `table`), then go from there. You can also try out the [debug API](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-debug.getinfo) (if it's available) to get even more info. If `data` is a table, try to loop over its content (`for k, v in pairs(r.data) do print k, v end`. If it contains your data, try to replace something, etc

Comment: (Added this as a comment as I'm not sure it's helpful at all, people familiar with krakend can certainly offer more and better insights)

Comment: @Neil, something new???